# Copying object of class A to object of Class B, where A and B have very similar composition

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following redundant code - copying a Class FeedDBTableRow's object into a Feed object - where they mostly have overlapping set of variables, and I am trying to copy those common set of variables. Is there a design pattern or an annotation processor that helps me reduce these (potentially bug-prone) lines of code?

The reason for doing this basically I want to use Retrofit with GSon and Realm (and Realm due to its own construction, needs the Pojo to extend from RealmObject class, while doing this creates a GSON error - it is documented at several places)

```
public static Feed getFeedFromDBFeedRow(FeedDBTableRow f){

    Feed x = new Feed();
    x.setId(f.getId());
    x.setText(f.getText());
    x.setTime_created(f.getTime_created());
    x.setTime_modified(f.getTime_modified());
    x.setComments_count(f.getComments_count());
    x.setLikes_count(f.getLikes_count());
    x.setFeed_type(f.getFeed_type());
    x.setObj_id(f.getObj_id());
    x.setImage(f.getImage());
    x.setUser_name(f.getUser_name());
    x.setUser_earthmile_points(f.getUser_earthmile_points());
    x.setLiked(f.isLiked());
    x.setCommented(f.isCommented());
    x.set_private(f.isIs_private());
    x.setUrl(f.getUrl());
    x.setFeed_creator_id(f.getFeed_creator_id());

    return x;
}
```

#### My Feed class is:

```
public class Feed {

    int id;
    String text;
    Date time_created;
    Date time_modified;
    int comments_count;
    int likes_count;
    String feed_type;
    int obj_id;
    String image;
    String user_name;
    String user_earthmile_points;
    boolean liked;
    boolean commented;
    boolean is_private;
    String url;
    int feed_creator_id;

    public Feed() {}        // required for being Parcelable
}
```

#### And the FeedDBTableRow class is :

```
public class FeedDBTableRow extends RealmObject{ // having this necessity to extend RealmObject is the source of all problem, but I have to do this, hence two classes with similar composition
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private Date time_created;
    private Date time_modified;
    private int comments_count;
    private int likes_count;
    private String feed_type;
    private int obj_id;
    private String image;
    private String user_name;
    private String user_earthmile_points;
    private boolean liked;
    private boolean commented;
    private boolean is_private;
    private String url;
    private int feed_creator_id;
}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: My question is how to avoid this redundant lines of code -is there an annotation processor that helps me?

Comment: Why not just have an internal `Feed` object inside your `FeedDBTableRow` instead of all those fields?

Comment: I tried doing it, but Realm.io needs just raw fields for database output - can't handle compound objects as members

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache BeanUtils: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/index.html
In particular, `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` might be something you find useful.

Comment: i have used apache's method several times.. its perfect for your solution but it will copy to other object only when that parameter is there in both object (also having same declaraion)

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Prashant - I am trying to use BeanUtils - but facing an error as I put here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641308/copying-object-of-class-a-to-object-of-class-b-where-a-and-b-have-very-similar?noredirect=1#comment43701864_27641308